# Unity bar doesn't hide

Tags: unity, graphics, autohide, 2d, panel

After switching the 'auto hide' function on and off under behaviour in appearance settings, the Unity bar doesn't automatically hide anymore! It's always visible at the left side! Here is a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g3gm4se8boqy5v/Schermafdruk%20van%202012-07-22%2017%3A31%3A33.png The Unity bar isn't placed over the program when it's maximised.

I just read [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/984477) that Unity 2D doesn't have a reset option (?) (my graphics card doesn't support Unity 3d acceleration)

How do I get back the standard Unity setting (that it hides automatically when a program is maximized)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have logged out and back in and it hasn't resolved itself, likely some of your settings have become corrupt.

The easiest way to fix this is with **`UbuntuTweak`**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

You can read more about it at [**webup8.org**](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/ubuntu-tweak-071-available-for-download.html)

The programs first page looks like this:

[image: Ubuntu tweak start page]

Click on the `Tweaks` and you will see:

[image: Tweaks]

Select Unity and then click on the arrow next to `Launcher Hide Mode`

[image]

As you are using Unity 2D you will have the option to `Auto-Hide` which will *always* hide it or `Intelli Hide`  which will only hide it if a window is in the way(The way it worked in both 2D and 3D until 12.04) just select one of the `Hide` options and then log out and back in, you should then have the launcher hiding correctly again.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpfull info! It hides again! :D Thank you

Comment: @SidneyDijkers glad I could help.